# Woocommerce пагинация работает без обновления страниц

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, pagination

Добрый день. Пагинация товаров работает без всяких нареканий, но при переходе на страницы контент обновляется без перезагрузки страницы и указания в адресной строке номера страницы. Как это можно исправить?
Нашел файл, который отвечает за пагинацию в woocommerce, но не могу разобраться что поменять, чтобы нумерация страниц отображалась в адресной строке сайта.

```
<?php
/**
 * Pagination - Show numbered pagination for catalog pages
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to     yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/pagination.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.2.2
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $wp_query;

if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 ) {
    return;
}
?>
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
    <?php
        echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args',     array(
        'base'         => esc_url_raw( str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', remove_query_arg( 'add-to-cart', get_pagenum_link( 999999999, false ) ) ) ),
        'format'       => '',
        'add_args'     => false,
        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
        'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text'    => '&larr;',
        'next_text'    => '&rarr;',
        'type'         => 'list',
        'end_size'     => 3,
        'mid_size'     => 3
    ) ) );
?>
</nav>
```

Comment: Это делает не WC, а используемая тема.

Comment: А где этот код может располагаться? Уже несколько дней бьюсь над этим вопросом.(

Comment: В functions.php или ещё где-то

Comment: А как этот код может выглядеть? Просмотрел каждую страничку в теме, но нигде ничего похожего на пагинацию не нашел.

Comment: Это делает ajax в теме. Соответственно в js, которые могут вызваться откуда угодно. Как правило темы с таким функционалом имеют настройку для вкл/выкл этого. Так что стоит просто изучить настройки темы.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь! Тему делал свою. На Wordpress сайт делаю первый раз, поэтому еще многого не понимаю. На данный момент моим спасением стал плагин, в следующий раз постараюсь обойтись без него.)

Answer (score 0):

Не нашел где это меняется, поэтому установил плагин [WP-PageNavi](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/)

и все заработало как надо.)